# why my click function not working in specific media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm just learning about front end developing. i have a problem to make an overlay navbar menu instead of dropown menu. when it reach extra small window (575.98 px below) the navbar menu change to overlay. when the window is above that, the navbar is dropdown.

i use jquery `$(window).width()` to check, if my window on extra small size when i click the hamburger icon, the overlay come out. but it doesn't happen in my code, the overlay came out, but it suddenly goes up again

does anyone can help me? i would appreciate any answer. thanks in advance !

```js
// initialize object
var overlayContent = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
var overlayBtn = $('.navbar-toggler');
var closeOverlayBtn = $('.closebtn');


 if($(window).width() < 575.98) {
  overlayBtn.on('click',function(){
   overlayContent.css('height', '100%');
   overlayContent.removeAttr('class');

   // remove attribute that related with collapse 
   $(this).removeAttr('data-toggle data-target aria-controls aria-expanded aria-label');
  });

  closeOverlayBtn.on('click',function(){
   overlayContent.css('height', '0');

   // add back attribute
   overlayBtn.attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
   overlayBtn.attr('data-target', '#navbarSupportedContent');
   overlayBtn.attr('aria-controls', 'navbarSupportedContent');
   overlayBtn.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
   overlayBtn.attr('aria-label', 'Toggle navigation');

   // add back class
   overlayContent.attr('class', 'collapse navbar-collapse');
  });
 }
 else {
  // don't do the click when windows width over 575.98 px
  overlayBtn.off("click");
  closeOverlayBtn.off("click");
 };
```

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  #navbarSupportedContent {

   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 #overlay-content {

   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 30px;
 }

 #navbarSupportedContent a {

   padding: 8px;   
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: #818181;
   display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="overlay-content">
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/jObWmab Please be sure to have post your entire code, maybe there is something else that is interfering.

Comment: have you try to run the snippet? if you hit the hamburger icon, it's drop down. but when you shrink your browser to extra small size and hit the icon again. the overlay wont come out. it just drop a bit and then goes up

Comment: Yes, I have. If I shrink the browser to extra-small size and then click on the hamburger icon  I see the overlay and it stays open until I click on the "x". You can see it in my CodePen. I am testing it on Chrome Browser, the latest version.